# How to find difference between two times?

Tags: php

I am using the following code for finding the time difference but it gives me wrong time difference. I followed following links [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php) and [this](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/) but the difference is wrong.

```
$diff = date_diff(date_create(date("Y-m-d h:i A", $this->start_time)), date_create(date("Y-m-d h:i A")));
echo '<span style = "color: #739e3b">'.$diff->d.' Day(s) : '.$diff->h.' Hr(s) : '.$diff->i.' Min(s)</span>';
```

Comment: Can you specify why you think the difference is wrong? What you expect to get and what you currently get?

Comment: I am testing it by comparing remaining time with a time difference calculator

Comment: How I and others can check if our answer provides proper difference?

Answer (score 5):

Procedural:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

This is the OOP way:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Here's the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
And here's a great library to make your life easier: https://carbon.nesbot.com

Comment: Timezones may be tricky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982412/php-diff-gives-incorrect-values-where-date1-2016-03-01

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = date_create('2015-01-26 12:01:00');
$end = date_create('2015-01-26 13:15:00');
$diff=date_diff($end,$start);
print_r($diff);
```